# Refactoring cut in DCG, general principles? [answerd by comments]

Tags: prolog, dcg, prolog-cut

Consider a clause with cut

```
f(X) :- g(X), !, h(X).
```

I think it is a common sense that we can refactor cuts as follows:

```
h1(X) :- !, h(X).
f(X) :- g(X), h1(X).
```

However, for DCGs, this kind of macro-like refactoring for cuts doesn't seem to work. For instance, I tried to refactor a DCG clause like this

```
f(X) --> g(X), !, h(X).
```

into something like below

```
h1(X) --> !, h(X).
f(X) --> g(X), h1(X).
```

but it just didn't work. That is, failure in `h(X)` in the latter while it didn't backtrack in the former before refactoring the cut.

Is there a general principles when refactoring DCGs with cuts? Or, some additional dark corners to consider when using cuts inside DCGs?

Comment: Your first observation is flawed already.  Take `g(1). g(2). h(2).` and query `?- f(X).`  This originally fails, but succeeds in your refactored `f/1`.

Comment: Your first example is not equivalent if there where more clauses of `f/1`, e.g. take `f(X):-g(X),!,h(X). f(hello).` is not the same as `f(X):-g(X),h1(X). f(hello). h1(X):-!, h(X).`

Comment: Oh, it doesn't even work with normal clauses. Thanks for both comments.